# Rails nested forms: f.input and input(f) difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

I doing some forms, and tried to made a nested form that way:

```
<%= form_for(@birth) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area(:obs) %>
    <%= f.fields_for :child_attributes do |ff| %>
        <%= text_field(:child_attributes, :earring) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in BirthsController, I can get the nested attributes that way:

```
child = params[:child_attributes]
```

But, if I change my nested form to:

```
<%= form_for(@birth) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area(:obs) %>
    <%= f.fields_for :child_attributes do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.text_field(:earring) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It does not work.
What's exactly the difference between them, and why the second way (that I think is more elegant) do not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text_field` method knows nothing about your object `@birth`, so the name of the field will just be `child_attributes`, that's why you can access it via `params[:child_attributes]`, but that's not what you want.

You should use `ff.text_field`. Then in your `Birth` model, add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_attributes
attr_accessible :child_attributes_attributes
```

Comment: that's it, thanks! Just one thing: attr_accessible :child_attributes without the last "_attributes" :)

Comment: Are you sure? I think you need the last _attributes. For instance, if you have `has_many :media`, and `f.fields_for :media...`, then you would need to have `attr_accessible :media_attributes`. So I don't see why the fact that your association is named "*_attributes" would change that...

Comment: yep... but your example is `attr_accessible :child_attributes_attributes` and I use `attr_accessible :child_attributes` and it works great.... I just change the way I get the values in my controller, I use `params[:birth][:child_attributes]`...

Comment: But you shouldn't have to do anything with `params[:birth][:child_attributes]`! That's the point of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, Rails will handle creating the child_attributes.